# How to compute this integral $\int_A\cos(x+y+x)\,dx\,dy\,dz$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

How to compute this integarl?

$$\int_A\cos(x+y+x)\,dx\,dy\,dz$$

where A is the unit ball $B(0,1)$ in $R^3$

Comment: is there a typo? should it be $\cos(x+y+z)$? any thoughts about the question?

Comment: Perhaps some symmetries of the ball and of the function will make this integral easier?

Comment: By applying an isometry $$\iiint_{B(0,1)}\cos(x+y+z)\,d\mu=\iiint_{B(0,1)}\cos\left(x\sqrt{3}\right)\,dx\,dy\,dz = 2\int_{0}^{1}\pi(1-x^2)\cos(\sqrt{3} x)\,dx $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw an $u$-axis through $O$ with $u=1$ at $\bigl({1\over\sqrt{3}},{1\over\sqrt{3}},{1\over\sqrt{3}}\bigr)\in S^2$. The planes $x+y+z={\rm const.}$ are orthogonal to this axis, whereby the plane $x+y+z=\sqrt{3}u$  has distance $|u|$ from $O$ and intersects the unit ball in a circular disc of radius $$r_u:=\sqrt{1-u^2}\qquad(-1\leq u\leq1)\ .$$
It follows that your integral is equal to
$$\int_{-1}^1\pi\, r_u^2\>\cos\bigl(\sqrt{3}\,u\bigr)\>du=\pi\int_{-1}^1(1-u^2)\cos \bigl(\sqrt{3}\,u\bigr)\>du\ .$$
The integral can be evaluated in elementary terms; the result is, according to Mathematica,
$${4\pi\over9}\bigl(\sqrt{3}\sin\sqrt{3}-3\cos\sqrt{3}\bigl)\ .$$